Impala Implad too many open unix socket
When testing Impala 4.2 on Redhat 7.x, a problem was discovered that the impalad service creates a huge number of unix sockets, which can be seen using lsof:
main 33789 impala 708u unix 0xffff8b2134213 0t0 12351515151 socket
After reaching the Open files limit, errors like this occur:
ERROR: Disk I/O error on datanode1:27000
Error reading from HDFS file: .....
Error(255): Unknow error 255
Root cause: BlockMissingException: Coud not obtain block
We have already increased the limit to 65000.
Also on the data node service the number of open files is also sharply increasing.
While impala create too many socket? How limit?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
